# Controlling "select all" behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css

While I'm writing to a textarea, text input or working in an iframe, "select all" only selects the text what's inside them.
I need to reach this kind of behaviour with a div (using CSS or JavaScript).

In a nutshell:

```
I shouldn't be selected on select all.
<div id="box">
I should be selected on select all.
</div>
```

*I'm working on a custom confirmation box in JavaScript and it would be weird if I click "select all" in the context menu or press Ctrl + A and select everything on the page: [simplified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bx3h8a31/).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class to the area you dont want it to be selected and use css like this like this:

```
.no_select { 
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}
```

See it in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bx3h8a31/1/)

Comment: I knew about this, but for some reason I didn't mind it in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure *exactly* what you're asking but here are two things that *may* help...

This CSS will stop users from highlighting things that shouldn't be highlighetd on a page...

```
* {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

And this javascript will enable a user to highlight and copy an item when he clicks on it...

```
onclick="this.focus(); this.select();"
```

NB: Webkit only CSS provided here as I only work in Chromium.